# Не отправляется сообщение через компонент ICQClient

Tags: delphi, icq

```
ICQClient1.SendSMS('+79500******','ПривеД МедвеД');
```

Почему-то не отправляет сообщение через данный компонент. Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, в чём я ошибся?!

Comment: Возможно, я не прав, но это наверника не весь ваш код для работы с клиентом. Вполне вероятно, что ошибка не конкретно в этой строке.

Comment: Яного работал с этим компанентом, естественно, что отправлять я начинаю после авторизации в ICQ
Он просто игнорирует данную строчку, и не чего не происходит, просто может кто работал с ним и знает в чём причина, я думаю что это может быть просто не совместимость с оператором БайкалВестКом, но вроде должен отправлять...

Comment: Ну а на другие номера все нормально?

Comment: Не пробовал, живу один, номер тоже один

Comment: Ну так начать то как раз и надо было со смены номера. Может и не в этом дело совсем - сервера полегли, хомяки кабели в дата-центре перегрызли, мало ли.

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю тут, возможно в операторе дело, а возможно и данная функция уже не работает не только у меня одного

Comment: А номер у Вас нормальный?
а то судя по куску кода это номер начинающийся на 00, может Вы хотите отправлять на короткие номера?

Comment: ну я же звёздачками закрыл остальные...Глупо было бы слать на короткие номер и возмущаться тут по этому поводу, номер обычый, сотовый, оператор БВК(БайкалВестКом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент TICQClient старый, после его выпуска протокол уже много раз меняли, так что вряд ли вообще что-то получится. Кроме того, большинство IM определят вашу программу как интернет-пейджер и проигнорируют отправляемые ею сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

ICQClient1.SendSMS(Edit1.Text, '(nik ,ICQ) ' + memo.Text);

Comment: на сегодняшний день у меня все работает стабильно ;)